# "What is use of androidx and can we use both androidx and appCompat?"

Tags: java, android, kotlin

"I am not able to use both android x as well as appCompat, is ther a way or i have to migrate all my code to androidX"

I tried putting in different module but it didn't worked

Do I  have to migrate if my compile sdk version is 28?

Comment: You have to use the [androidx.appcompat:appcompat](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat) library. You **can't** use androidx and support libraries together.

Answer (score 0):

You can just migrate your project to androidx by selecting Refactor-->Migrate to AndroidX. It will automatically import the library `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;` So you no need to change anything in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Androidx is the latest SDK update of android, It will provide you backward compatibility and to get rid of support libraries, It indluded all these support libraries in AndroidX package.
You can't use any AndroidX library or can't access any of its packages unless you migrate your app's code to AndroidX. I'll prefer you to migrate it as it will increase support.